# Modify hour in datetimeindex in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension, datetime-format

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
master.head(5)
Out[73]: 
            hour    price
day                      
2014-01-01     0  1066.24
2014-01-01     1  1032.11
2014-01-01     2  1028.53
2014-01-01     3   963.57
2014-01-01     4   890.65


In [74]: master.index.dtype

Out[74]: dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

What I need to do is update the hour in the index with the hour in the column but the following approaches don't work:

```
In [82]: master.index.hour = master.index.hour(master['hour'])

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

In [83]: master.index.hour = [master.index.hour(master.iloc[i,0]) for i in len(master.index.hour)]

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How to proceed?

Comment: And what is your expected result?

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear, what EdChum suggested gives the expected result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC I think you want to construct a `TimedeltaIndex`:

```
In [89]:
df.index += pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['hour'], unit='h')
df

Out[89]:
                     hour    price
2014-01-01 00:00:00     0  1066.24
2014-01-01 01:00:00     1  1032.11
2014-01-01 02:00:00     2  1028.53
2014-01-01 03:00:00     3   963.57
2014-01-01 04:00:00     4   890.65
```

Just to compare against using `apply`:

```
In [87]:
%timeit df.index + pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['hour'], unit='h')
%timeit df.index + df['hour'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(x, 'h'))

1000 loops, best of 3: 291 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 ms per loop
```

You can see that using a TimedeltaIndex is significantly faster

Comment: Awesome! I've been at it for an hour and didn't manage to do it!

Comment: construct a Timedeltaindex, will be much faster, have posted timings

Comment: you don't even need to explicity construct a TimedeltaIndex, just ``df.index + pd.Timedelta('1h')``

Comment: @Jeff but that adds 1 hour to each index value, the OP want's the hour column added to each index entry

Comment: FYI, I would never even show ``.apply`` unless its the ONLY way which is rarely the case. Its always slow and just confusing.

Comment: @Jeff I agree, it always tends to be my first response before I realise there must be vectorised method, will remove

Answer (score 0):

```
master.index = 
pd.to_datetime(master.index.map(lambda x : x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) + '-' + master.hour.map(str) , format='%Y-%m-%d-%H.0')
```

Comment: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'str'

Comment: you may need to convert `value` to `string` , check the updated answer

Comment: @DavidW I've updated my answer , I think it's now simpler and even clearer

Comment: ValueError: time data '2014-01-01 00:00:00-0.0' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d-%H.0' (match

Comment: I though that your index is of type string , check the updated answer

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.